# Python removing negative items in a list in a nested for loop

Tags: python, list, for-loop

I'm trying to make a program that a. Takes several numbers from the user, separated by spaces, b. Removes any positive number (greater than -1), and c. Prints out those numbers from largest to smallest (-1 -2 -3 -20 -60).

It appears that whenever the for loop to determine if the number in the list is greater than -1 (and thus should be deleted), the program picks (seemingly) random numbers to remove.  I'm bad with lists (indices, what's callable, subscriptable, etc).  Everything else seems to be running fine, save for this for loop.  What should I do?

```
numbers = input("Let's sort a list of numbers.  Give me a list of numbers, each separated by a space: ").split()
new_list = list(map(int,numbers))

for x in new_list:
    if x >= 0:
        new_list.pop

new_list.sort()
new_list.reverse()

def list_to_string(list):
    string = ""
    for x in list:
        string += str(x) + " "
    return string

print(list_to_string(new_list))
```

Input 1: 62 19 4 3 18 5 7

Output 1: 19 5 3

What I want for Output 1: *nothing*

Input 2: -18 4 -1 -39 -5 92 37 42

Output 2: 37 -1 -5 -18 -39

What I want for Output 2: -1 -5 -18 -39

Comment: `new_list.pop` isn't doing anything. You need something like `new_list.pop(some_index)`. Also, it's a bad idea to remove items from a `list` while iterating over it.

Comment: The function signature for `list_to_string` is `def list_to_string(list):`, however, within it you iterate over `numbers`. Is this intentional?

Comment: @Axe319, no, it's not intentional.  Just corrected it.  In addition, is it correct to say new_list.pop(new_list[x])?

Comment: You would need to do something like `for index, x in enumerate(new_list):` and then `new_list.pop(index)`. However, that will lead to surprising results since you're modifying the `list` as you're iterating over it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can construct your list in one line then print that list by unpacking its sorted output as follows:

```
numbers = input("Let's sort a list of numbers. Give me a list of numbers, each separated by a space: ")
new_list = [n for n in map(int, numbers.split()) if n < 0]
print(*sorted(new_list, reverse=True))
```

Answer (score 0):

Your call to `new_list.pop` doesn't do anything because you're not actually calling it (i.e. you didn't use the parentheses).  The pop() method needs to be called with an index to remove a specific position. With only parentheses it removes the last position.

So your removal loop needs to get the indexes along with the values in the list.  You can get that using the enumerate() function.

Removing from within the for loop on the list itself will cause the process to skip items.  When you remove an item, all other items are shifted by one position but the loop will still advance to the next index so every item that follows a removal will be skipped.

You would either have to work your way through the list backwards or rebuild the list by filtering out the excluded values:

```
# backward loop

for i,x in reversed(list(enumerate(new_list))):
    if x > -1: 
        new_list.pop(i)
```

...

```
# rebuilding the list

new_list = [ x for x in new_list if x < 0 ]
```

After that, sorting the list in decreasing order can be done directly in the sort method with the reverse parameter:

```
new_list.sort(reverse=True)
```

and the print function can print all the values separated by spaces using unpacking ( `*` before the parameter expands it into individual parameters)

```
print(*new_list)
```

A different approach would be to sort your list before cleaning it out.  This will place all the items you want to remove at the beginning of the list.  So you can keep removing the first item  until the first one is an item that you want to keep (or the list is empty):

```
new_list.sort(reverse=True)
while new_list and new_list[0] > -1:
    new_list.pop(0)

print(*new_list)
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe you just need the negative values to be exist in your list.
in your code you are calling `new_list.pop` but this have no meaning in this context as you are not giving a parameters to it.
you can use this code to pop an elements from a list `new_list.pop(element)`, but this will not work too as the iteration will continue and you will miss the next element after the deleted one.

you simply can achieve the requirements using more combined code like..

```
numbers = input("Let's sort a list of numbers.  Give me a list of numbers, each separated by a space: ").split()
new_list = [int(i) for i in numbers if int(i) < 0]
new_list.sort(reverse=True)
print(new_list)
```